# Blocking torrent in Android

Tags: stock-android, dns, torrents, bittorrent

Is it possible to completely block torrents in android?
I have tried to use many porn blockers like BlockerX, Remojo etcetera. I can block the torrent websites by blocking the keyword - 'torrent' .But there are many torrent search apps like Torrcrow and Torrent Revolution which can still fetch the torrent results. I also used SafeDns to block it but they all seem impotent.

Can we block torrent downloading at system level? Like making it impossible for torrent client to connect with peers or disallowing the torrent search in different apps.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I want to bolster self control that's why I need to implement this feature.

Comment: There's no universally working method. See [How to effectively block torrents on my network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/42145/207688) and [How to block torrent sites?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/122617/207688) to get a general idea why it's so.

Comment: @Irfan Latif...Isn't it possible after rooting the device?

Comment: May be. But what would you do with root? Blocking ports or IP addresses, DPI, uninstalling apps. These can all be done without root too but aren't very effective.